# Arrange descending order and select top 3 in R

Tags: r, dplyr

Data:

**d2**

```
# A tibble: 5 x 2
  Dist      n
  <chr> <int>
1 003     194
2 011     180
3 013     157
4 017     279
5 026     208
```

From the above data "d2" I want to order the values in descending order for column 'n'. Also want top 2 values.

When I am using

```
arrange(desc(d2$n))
```

It is showing error:

```
Error in UseMethod("arrange_") : 
  no applicable method for 'arrange_' applied to an object of class "c('integer', 'numeric')"
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Please provide a minimal working example.

Comment: Try `head(d2[ order(-d2$n), ], 3)`

Comment: Look at the sintax in the proposed duplicate, it should be: `arrange(d2, desc(n))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

since you did not provide your data, here is a solution for some random data:

```
d2 <- tibble(m = runif(5)*10, n = rnorm(5)) 

d2 %>%
  arrange(desc(n)) %>%
  slice(1:3)
```

Alternatively you can use the `top_n` function:

```
d2 %>% top_n(3, n)
```

The difference between these two methods is that `top_n` does not sort the result.